# How do getters, mutations and actions play together in Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I'm curious about Vuex for my personal project and more specifically how the different properties play together. I apologize in advance if this is a repetitive question.

I'm using Vue3 and this is the way I've configured the store:

```js
// store/index.js
import { createStore } from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";
let connected = false;
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.baseURL = import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL;
export default createStore({
  state: {
    connected,
  },
  getters: {
    getConnected: (state) => {
      return state.connected;
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    setConnected(state, isConnected) {
      console.log("in mutations");
      return (state.connected = isConnected);
    },
  },
  actions: {
    isConnected: ({ commit }) => {
      axios
        .get("/auth/me")
        .then(() => {
          console.log("here positive");
          commit("setConnected", true);
        })
        .catch(() => {
          console.log("here negative");
          commit("setConnected", false);
        });
    },
  },
  modules: {},
});
```

The `state` is what we're storing, the `mutations` are the operations on the state and the `actions` are the operations on the `mutations` via `commits`.

Here's my Vue page:

```js
<template>
  <v-row justify="start">
    <nav>
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link :to="connected ? '/me' : '/signup'">{{
        connected ? "Profile Page" : "Sign up"
      }}</router-link>
      |
      <router-link :to="connected ? '/logout' : '/login'">{{
        connected ? "Logout" : "Login"
      }}</router-link>
    </nav>
  </v-row>
</template>
<script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "NavBar",
  data() {
    return {
      connected: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapGetters(["getConnected"]),
    ...mapActions(["isConnected"]),
  },
  mounted() {
    this.connected = this.getConnected();
    console.log("connected", this.connected);
  },
};
</script>

<style>
nav {
  padding: 30px;
}

nav a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

nav a.router-link-exact-active {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

My question, how do I trigger the `actions`? Do I need to explicitly call the method via `mapActions` or am I missing something?

TIA!

Comment: If you are just starting with Vuex, you better take a look at Pinia, since that is the new replacement for Vuex. It has a simpler pattern, without the mutations. https://pinia.vuejs.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call it like any other method:

```
async mounted() {
  await this.isConnected()
  this.connected = this.getConnected();
  console.log("connected", this.connected);
},
```

more [`here`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions)